# Validation close to training accuracy in a cross validation but model is bad

Tags: neural-network

This is a question from an exam:

> Your task was to build a model that predicts whether an e-mail is spam or not spam
> for a mail service. You had access to a huge data set of more than 10 Million mails,
> where 99% of the mails were not spam. Your model always achieved an accuracy of
> 99% on both your validation and training set using 100-fold cross-validation. The
> owner of the mail service was very impressed by the high accuracy and your model
> is used to ﬁlter real spam mails. However, users of the mail service complain that
> spam mails are not ﬁltered at all. What is the most likely reason for this?
> What is a possible solution?

So I think the reason might be that the model always says that an email is not spam. But I am lost on the second part (maybe the first as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes the problem is that the training dataset, is very imbalanced.
And if the model predicts not-spam for every email, it will anyway end-up with 99% accuracy.

There are 3 ways to handle this:

1- balance the dataset by under sampling (Downsampling) the majority class which is "not-spam" emails, and make the dataset more balanced.

2- use class-weights. See the link below:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/improve-class-imbalance-class-weights/

3- The most important approcah is to use the following factors as Performance metric instead of accuracy:

Precision: True Positives / All Predicted Positives

Recall: True Positives / All actual positives